# How to achieve .svn folder only in root?

Tags: svn

When adding a folder to version-control .svn folders are created. I've seen both:

- .svn folder is only created on the root of the folder in version control
- .svn folder is created on every subfolder of the folder in version control

I would like to enforce .svn only created on root-folder. What does it depend on whether strateygy is used?

For better understanding what I want to achieve: I have sources created by a tool, that I want to add to svn (please no discussion if it's reasonable to add generated sources to version control). When creating a new build all folders are deleted and newly created, so all my .svn folders are deleted and svn gets confused. If I had .svn folder only on root it wouldn't be deleted.

Maybe somebody knows a better way to achieve this.

Comment: I thinks that's a global change in the working copy from 1.7? http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.7.html#wc-ng I guess you might be mixing your client versions?

Comment: Just upgrade. The "scattered `.svn` folders" working copy format was removed two years ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Former versions of svn were creating `.svn` in each folder. Since version 1.7 `.svn` folder is created once per working copy.

So if you want to have a single `.svn` directory, you must use client version 1.7 or better.

Comment: Also, remember that every external has it's own `.svn` folder as well.